# click function on toggled button class

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of divs which are tied to a button which toggles show/hide behaviors.  I've adjusted the parent div to 100vh, and each individual div to 50vh, and and everything was displaying perfectly, except the buttons that check the user input and somehow went over to the right. I tried various vh combinations, and putting the buttons inside each individual div is what ultimately worked.  Now of course, I have a button with an id that no longer works because there is one button inside each div.  Giving each button a different ID isn't an option because they're attached to a single click handler.

Now of course, I have a button which requires a click handler and where the ID is broken.  I tried using a class and looked up adding a click behavior to a class, and none of the suggestions on SO worked.  I tried using a child selector with the class (where the button is a child of the div id).

Here's a mini code sample of how it used to work.  How can I have a working click function (without resorting to separate id's for each button - that would be a lot of id's) where I have a separate button inside of each div?

HTML:

```
<div id="quiz" style="height:100vh;">
  <div id="divone" style="height:50vh;">
    Div One!
  </div>
  <div id="divtwo" style="display:none">
    Div Two!
  </div>
  <button id="clickything">Click me!</button>
  </div
```

JS/ jQuery:

```
var divs = ["divone", "divtwo", "divthree"]
var i = 0
$("#clickything").click(function() {
    $("#" + divs[0]).hide();
    $("#" + divs[1]).show();
})
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Click the button and toggle between div1 and div2?

Comment: This is a simplified version of what I'm doing - there is a question div, and the button hides the current div and shows the result div, and then another button in the result div hides the result and shows the next question. So when you click the button you get either the result for the current question, or if you're on the result, you get the next question.

Comment: As a temporary fix, I've given each button its own id, but ...  this isn't a scalable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a button (if it's a quiz) instead of uses clicking the div in question.

It would be a better UI (from my inference of goal) and simpler JS

If both divs are in a parent you can use that to hide the other.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point.  What would a user click if not a button?

Comment: One of the two divs.